# Changing brightness of display (C#)

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# setting screen brightness Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194006/c-sharp-setting-screen-brightness-windows-7)

I searched online for some topics about chanding the brightness of the display through C#.
For the most part, I got links to change the gamma in Windows ([here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47355/Setting-Screen-Brightness-in-C) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013622/adjust-screen-brightness-using-c-sharp)) and this is working fine for me. But I was wondering if this is the correct way of reducing the brightness or dimming the display (does this save power as reducing the brightness of monitor does?)

Is this a good way to reduce brightness or is there a better way to do the same? 
I'm on Windows 7 (I forgot what the default gamma value of windows is?! Somebody?)

Comment: I doubt that the solution provided there actually changes the brightness on the monitor side. I do not see any reference to DDC only Windows. @Cipher can obviously test it, but if it doesn't actually communicate with the monitor the results might not be that great.

Comment: Something else arguably related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4373/does-a-webpage-with-a-black-background-save-energy which infers that changing color brightness on LCD monitors at a software level (as in not adjusting the hardware's back lighting level) should have a negligible effect.     This doesn't take into account monitors that actively adjust the back lighting based on the image they are trying to render, but I suspect this could vary dramatically based on manufacturer, etc,etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrast/Brightness are properties inside of the physical monitor; not the software. Windows only knows Gamma. Most tools and guides you will find, will secretly edit gamma, which is obviously not the same as brightness/contrast.

But I did find this link: ["How to Control the ‘Real’ Brightness and Contrast of Monitors by Software"](http://www.instantfundas.com/2011/10/how-to-control-real-brightness-and.html)

This is not a technical explanation of how it's done, it only lists problems with common 'tools' that claim to be able to do it. Instead it demonstrates the use of a couple of programs that actually communicate with the monitor. But the monitor as well as the video card, need to support the DDC protocol.

Maybe you can use this [DDC protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel) to roll your own approach in C#. There might even be libraries already, but if not; it will be a difficult implementation I guess.