# WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods - Not Supported in Windows 7

Tags: c#, wmi

WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods is not supported in Windows 7. What could be possible reasons. I'm trying to use WmiSetBrightness to get and set brightness levels and values in c# application.

Comment: What have you tried?  I found this within 10 seconds on Google.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194006/c-sharp-setting-screen-brightness-windows-7

Comment: I tried it, but I'm getting it working in some systems but not all. In some systems I'm getting "Not Supported" when I used - WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods. So try to see how to get it working in all systems

Answer (score 0):

It could be simply that the PC doesn't support adjusting the brightness through software in the official way - for example, some laptops support it through the Mobility Centre, others only through proprietary software and others only through hardware keys.

If you're seeing the issue on some of a number of identical machines, make sure the graphics drivers are up to date.