# Is there a .NET API to control entire screen hue / colors?

Tags: .net, windows, winapi

Is there a .NET API to control entire screen hue / colors ?
I'm trying to do something along the lines of what flux does and I assume there must be a programmatic way to control these properties. The built in color calibration UI can do it, and I'm wondering how they do this.

If not in .NET, is there a winapi way of accomplishing this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of an existing method in .NET to adjust the screen colors, but you can call [SetDeviceGammaRamp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd372194.aspx). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8194095/4896941) has C# code to call SetDeviceGammaRamp.